# Python: Turn List of Tuples into Dictionary of Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

so I have a bit of an issue on my hands. I have a list of tuples (made up of a level number and message) which will eventually become an HTML list. My issues is that before this happens, I would like to turn the tuples values into a dictionary of nested dictionaries. So here is the example:

```
# I have this list of tuples in format of (level_number, message)
tuple_list = [(1, 'line 1'), (2, 'line 2'), (3, 'line 3'), (1, 'line 4')]

# And I want to turn it into this
a_dict = {
    'line 1': {
        'line 2': {
            'line 3': {}
        }
    }, 
    'line 4': {}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as long as it is valid Python 3. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean depth in the resulting dictionary by the level_number? So first element of tuple as 1 means its at the root-level of the dictionary. But where does the information come from that "deeper levels" are nested into "line 1" and not into "line 4"? Sorry if I am not recognizing the pattern here

Comment: What is the relation between line 1, line 2 and line 3 that you can group on? For e.g. Can they be considered objects and associated with each other ?

Comment: I want to be clear that the reason you're having a problem is because of your data structure. If you have any control of this data, please PLEASE change your data structure rather than implement any solution here. If you have no control of the data, you can treat this like a tree. It's probably more sane to build a `class TreeNode` that tracks its parent and children.

Comment: To @Minato, yes, level_number could be considered depth. And the depth has to do with the nesting. The strings are irrelvant to the sorting. So if a value has a depth of 3, it will be nested under the closest vlaue with a depth of 2 before it.

Comment: To @Versatile , yes, each lower value is associated with the closest higher value.

Comment: And to @AdamSmith, this is related to a Markdown processing project, so no, I have zero control over what information is given. If you would be willing to come up with an example of what you mean by 'TreeNode', that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment, you should STRONGLY consider changing your incoming data structure if you have any control at all over it. A sequential list of tuples is definitely not ideal for what you're doing here. However it is possible if you treat it like a tree. Let's build a (sane) data structure to parse this with

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, level, parent=None):
        self.children = []
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.parent = parent

    def make_child(self, othername, otherlevel):
        other = self.__class__(othername, otherlevel, self)
        self.children.append(other)
        return other
```

Now you should be able to iterate over your data structure in some sensible way

```
def make_nodes(tuple_list):
    """Builds an ordered grouping of Nodes out of a list of tuples
    of the form (level, name). Returns the last Node.
    """

    curnode = Node("root", level=-float('inf'))
    # base Node who should always be first.

    for level, name in tuple_list:
        while curnode.level >= level:
            curnode = curnode.parent
            # if we've done anything but gone up levels, go
            # back up the tree to the first parent who can own this
        curnode = curnode.make_child(name, level)
        # then make the node and move the cursor to it
    return curnode
```

Once your structure is complete, you can iterate on it. Doesn't much matter here if you go depth-first or breadth-first, so let's do a DFS just for ease of implementation.

```
def parse_tree(any_node):
    """Given any node in a singly-rooted tree, returns a dictionary
    of the form requested in the question
    """

    def _parse_subtree(basenode):
        """Actually does the parsing, starting with the node given
        as its root.
        """

        if not basenode.children:
            # base case, if there are no children then return an empty dict
            return {}
        subresult = {}
        for child in basenode.children:
            subresult.update({child.name: _parse_subtree(child)})
        return subresult

    cursor = any_node
    while cursor.parent:
        cursor = cursor.parent
        # finds the root node
    result = {}
    for child in cursor.children:
        result[child.name] = _parse_subtree(child)
    return result
```

Then feed in your tuple list *et voila*

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'line 1'), (2, 'line 2'), (3, 'line 3'), (1, 'line 4')]

last_node = make_nodes(tuple_list)
result = parse_tree(last_node)
# {'line 1': {'line 2': {'line 3': {}}}, 'line 4': {}}
```

Comment: glad I could help. Was a fun waste of a lunch break ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have three levels, something like following would do:

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'line 1'), (2, 'line 2'), (3, 'line 3'), (1, 'line 4')]

a_dict = {}

for prio, key in tuple_list:
    if prio == 1:
        a_dict[key] = {}
        first_level = key
    if prio == 2:
        a_dict[first_level][key] = {}
        second_level = key
    if prio == 3:
        a_dict[first_level][second_level][key] = {}
    # So on ...
print a_dict
```

This also assumes that hierarchies are listed in order, meaning level 1, level 1', level 2, level 3 would be a single dict for level 1, and a hierarchal order like level 1' -> level 2 -> level 3. So the following

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'line 5'), (1, 'line 1'), (2, 'line 2'), (3, 'line 3'), (1, 'line 4')]
```

Would yield the following :

```
{'line 1': {'line 2': {'line 3': {}}}, 'line 4': {}, 'line 5': {}}
```

Or a little more complicated:

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'line 1'), (2, 'line 2'), (2, 'line 6'), (3, 'line 3'), (3, 'line 7'), (1, 'line 4'), (1, 'line 5')]
```

would yield

```
{'line 1': {'line 2': {}, 'line 6': {'line 3': {}, 'line 7': {}}}, 'line 4': {}, 'line 5': {}}
```

Since your levels are not limited to a small number, **it's not a good approach to just do it through plain IFs**. It's better to construct a tree, then traverse the tree and create the representation you want. Doing so is also easy, you have several root nodes (where parent=None), each one has a list of children and this repeats for the children, so you have a tree. You now start from the root and make the ordering you want !

It's easily implementable and I guess you get the idea !

Comment: You have the correct idea with things like the 'more complicated' example, but I would be happier if the function could go 5 levels deep, please.

Comment: @tedm1106 its actually exactly the same as what I've provided. The code is not going to be *so beautiful* with four ifs, but you get the idea and probably can improve it to work without the ifs.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is pretty obvious how this could be extended :P

Comment: this isn't bad, but has the potential to break on nonstandard (but potentially valid!) levels like `[(1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), (1, "spam"), (3, "eggs")]`. I'm not sure what a "correct" interpretation of the jump from 1 -> 3 would be (mine just ignores it and treats the "3" like a "2"), but it's not raising a `KeyError`

Comment: The way your answer deals with it @AdamSmith is perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah it's the perfect solution (easy, short, fast), but for a *limited specific* problem, as it gets larger and broader, the OP has to use a tree like solution as you've provided.